# Intellij - Why the symbol of class does not show?

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, icons, symbols

Why the symbol of each class doesn't show? 
It shown the J icon instead of C.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen in all projects? Can you share a sample if it's project specific? Does removing [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) and starting from scratch helps?

Comment: It's interesting that your Interface files show the correct icon. To me this rules out a potential configuration issue. As such, my leading theory is that the indexing cache got corrupted. Try _File > Invalidate Caches & Restart_. Select the "Invalidate Caches and restart" option in the dialog. After the restart, let IDEA (re)index the project and I suspect you will be all set.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is some misconfiguration in your project's module, make sure that **src** folder marked as **Sources** in **Project Structure** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>) > **Modules**, then choose **src** folder and click on *Mark as: **Sources***

Also make sure that Project SDK is setup properly, **Project Structure** > **Project**

Comment: didn't work for me  :/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the visuals of the IDEA UI in your screenshot, the `src` folder is correctly marked as **Sources**.  But the ".java" files are marked as "package-info.java" files.

In a quick test, it looks like IDEA considers them classes as long as they have a valid `class` statement.  They do, don't they?